# XmlNode.InnerXml property - omit xmlns attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

I have some code to replace the root node name of an XML document while retaining its namespace.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
Stream inStream = inmsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream();
doc.Load(inStream);

XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode replacement = doc.SelectSingleNode("/*/*[1]");

XmlNode newRoot = doc.CreateElement(replacement.Name);
XmlAttribute xmlns = (XmlAttribute)root.Attributes["xmlns"].Clone();
newRoot.Attributes.Append(xmlns);
newRoot.InnerXml = root.InnerXml; //the problem is here!

doc.ReplaceChild(newRoot, root);
```

With a document that begins like this:

```
<OLD_ROOT xmlns="http://my.xml.namespace">
    <NEW_ROOT>
```

It results in:

```
<NEW_ROOT xmlns="http://my.xml.namespace">
     <NEW_ROOT xmlns="http://my.xml.namespace">
```

The second `xmlns` is because the `InnerXml` property apparently sets it on the first node of its contents! What can I do to circumvene this, without having to remove it afterwards?

### Cannot remove it afterwards:

Tried with the following code

```
XmlNode first_node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/*/*[1]");
XmlAttribute excess_xmlns = first_node.Attributes["xmlns"];
first_node.Attributes.Remove(excess_xmlns);
```

But this does not work as `xmlns` apparently does not exist as an attribute on that node!

Comment: Why bother? It looks redundant but harmless. And all this is so much easier with XDocument.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, hmm. Please elaborate on XDocument?

Comment: `doc.Root.Name = replacement.Name;`

Comment: @HenkHolterman wow, I never knew it could be that easy. Surprised I didn't find this myself because I did plenty of research. Thanks!

Comment: I've not tested if this solves your problem, and from the other comments/answers it looks like there's probably a better solution, but you may be unable to access the namespace declaration attribute because it's in a namespace itself ("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two changes:

1. Instead of adding an `xmlns` attribute after you create `newRoot`, specify the namespace as the second argument in the call to `doc.CreateElement`. This ensures that the `NamespaceURI` property is set correctly.
2. Instead of copying `InnerXml` (which results in redundant `xmlns` attributes), use `AppendChild` to move each child node one at a time. This will likely be more efficient anyway.

Thus:

```
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode replacement = doc.SelectSingleNode("/*/*[1]");

XmlNode newRoot = doc.CreateElement(replacement.Name, replacement.NamespaceURI);
while (root.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
    newRoot.AppendChild(root.FirstChild);

doc.ReplaceChild(newRoot, root);
```